# Unable to get the Chrome debugger to work via launch in Visual Studio Code for an Angular 8 project

Tags: angular, typescript, chrome-debugging

Upon upgrading Angular to version 8, I am now unable to run the Chrome debugger within Visual Studio Code.

I have not changed my launch.json which is similar to the following:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Chrome (https)",
  "url": "https://myhost.domain.com:4200",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

I launch the Angular app via the following command

```
ng serve --host myhost.domain.com --ssl --disableHostCheck
```

This was working for a long time until the upgrade. I was able to launch Chrome and debug different components in Angular. Now all it does is state "Unverified Breakpoint"

I tried the following:

- Changing the webRoot folder location to different possible locations. I did notice that there is a new message on the output, when I serve the app. (https://myhost.domain.com:4200/webpack-dev-server/
  ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
  ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html)
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling the Visual Studio Code Extension
- Adding SourceMap: true
- Creating a brand new Angular project using ng new test-project and attempting to debug this project and it does the same.

Here is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "my-application",
  "version": "0.7.2",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^8.1.1",
    "@datorama/akita": "^4.5.0",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^5.0.2",
    "angular-pipes": "^9.0.2",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "speed-measure-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Here is what ng version looks like:

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.1
Node: 10.15.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.1.1
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.801.1
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/cdk                      8.1.0
@angular/material                 8.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  8.1.1
@schematics/angular               8.1.1
@schematics/update                0.801.1
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.35.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The debugging `launch.json` and `tasks.json` configurations have changed for Angular 8 (both were recently updated July 2019)

You can find links and details for the most popular [Debugging Recipes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/debugging-recipes) on the VSCode documentation site.

The specific one for Angular is on the vscode-recipies GitHub page: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI

*They change too often to make it worth while posting the full configs here, so just putting in the links*

Comment: Thanks for the information. This was very helpful. A bit disappointing the setup and configuration is more complex making it this type of of debugging non-intuitive. I would have never figured this out on my own without opening up this posting.